# Google Charts API Datetime Error from MySQL with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I'm trying to use datetime from a mysql database in Google Charts along with price data.

Here's the relevant code:

```
     $sql2 = "SELECT priceLBTC,dt FROM prices ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50";
            $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
            $bitcoinPriceArr = array();
            $dateArr = array();
            if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                $i=-1;
                while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $i++;
                    if ($i%1) continue;
                    $dateArr[] = $row["dt"];
                    $bitcoinPriceArr[] = round($row["priceLBTC"], 2);
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
$conn->close();
```

And

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAxisTickColors);

function drawAxisTickColors() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Price');
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');

 data.addRows([
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    $bitcoinArray2 = array_reverse($bitcoinPriceArr);
    $dateArr2 = array_reverse($dateArr);

    foreach ($bitcoinArray2 as $v) {
       echo "[".$v.", new Date(".$dateArr2[$i].")]";
        $i++;
       if ($i < count($bitcoinArray2)) {
          echo ", ";
       }
    }
    ?>
  ]);
```

I think it has something to do with the formatting of the datetime. I'm not sure how to fix the error. I'm trying to have the datetime on the X axis and the Price on the Y.

EDIT:

I added new Date(), but I get a new error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.
```

The format for datetime should be: new Date(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds). I guess a better question now is how can I format datetime from MySQL into the above format readable by the google charts API?

Comment: `DataTable` expects a date not a string, try wrapping with `new Date('formatted date here')`

Comment: in your latest edit, it appears that you are not passing a string to `new date()`. try adding an apostrophe before and after, like this --> `echo "[".$v.", new Date('".$dateArr2[$i]."')]";`

Comment: I deleted all PHP and used a javascript array instead to add rows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487786/using-datetime-as-values-on-x-axis-in-google-charts/34487981?noredirect=1#comment56718971_34487981